# Run scala app with maven dependencies plus some java code

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have created a Scala application. This application has some maven dependencies. But this application has also some java code. Scala code is under

```
src/main/scala/...
```

and the java code is under

```
src/main/java/...
```

which I use through scala. The main class is a scala object (not java). I compile the application successfully via IntelliJ. When I try to run the application using:

```
scala -J-Xmx4g MyApp.jar
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$tryClass$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:43)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$tryClass$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:43)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$opt$1.apply(Exception.scala:119)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$opt$1.apply(Exception.scala:119)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:103)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:119)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.tryClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:42)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.tryToInitializeClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:39)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.tryToInitializeClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:63)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.run(MainGenericRunner.scala:13)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runJar(MainGenericRunner.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:69)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Note that I can run the application from the IDE. Also note that I have added some maven plugins as suggested from other websites with similar exceptions. The plugins are:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

What is the reason of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was quite simple. The folder scala had to be marked as "Sources Root" and the folder java had to be marked as "Generated Sources Root" from IntelliJ.

The application now works as expected.